# Inconsistent date time formatting

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format date time.

But it results inconsistently as either:

`May 9 2020 @ 11.50`

or

`09 May 2020 11.50 pm`

Why? I am expecting to receive 09 May 2020 11.50 pm consistently.

```js
const f = {
  "year": "numeric",
  "month": "short",
  "day": "2-digit",
  "hour": "2-digit",
  "minute": "2-digit",
  "hour12": true
};

const date = '2020-05-09T22:50:21.817Z';

const formatDateTime = (userLocale, dateTimeFormat, date) => {
    const dateDate = new Date(date);

    return dateDate.toLocaleDateString(userLocale, dateTimeFormat)
        .replace(',', ' ')
        .replace(',', ' @');
};

const result = formatDateTime('en-GB', f, date);

console.log(result);
```

Same logic, different results.

[image: May 9 2020 @ 11.50 Screenshot]

[image: 09 May 2020 11.50 pm Screenshot]

====UPDATE====

You can replicate the issue this way.

Go to an example site like: https://americanexpress.com/en-us/referral

Then browser inspect, go to console and paste above code in there.

Will see: 'May 9  2020 @ 11:50'

Do the same on another empty tab.

Will see: '09 May 2020 11.50 pm'

Comment: Please post an text based content as text in the question rather than as images of text

Comment: @phuzi I have added text based above. The images are to show case inconsistent results.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are seeing different results in the same browser with the same code?

Comment: @phuzi Yes, same Chrome browser, same code. Different tabs.

Comment: Can't reproduce. _"same Chrome browser, same code. Different tabs"_ - different tabs containing _what_, at the point when you execute this? Are they blank? Or is any page currently loaded into them?

Comment: What do you expect that this `.replace(',', ' ').replace(',', ' @');` does? Is there any case where there is more then one `,` in the string?

Comment: @CBroe Pls see update above. I've given steps on how you can reproduce.

Comment: That page has specified `<html lang="en-US">`, I am guessing that somehow creates a "context" that also influences the locale in the console. What do you get when you test the same thing on a page, that specifies `en-GB` there?

Comment: @CBroe Seeing same issue on another url which has <html lang="en-GB">. https://americanexpress.com/en-gb/referral

Comment: Maybe the empty tab still has a different locale set by default, based on your system's settings. But, more important than everything discussed so far - what is the _actual_ problem you need to solve here? I am guessing "JavaScript code copy&pasted into the browser console" is not the _actual_ use case/ problem you are struggling with, so ... what is?

Comment: @CBroe In my React app, I am calling this date time format function. And I end up with the incorrect format 100% of the time.
Trying to solve that. Thus was trying it out in console where I noticed this inconsistency. I am based in the UK if that matters.

Comment: Is your react act _specifying_ its locale, resp. that of its content, anywhere?

Comment: @CBroe I'm not setting anything specific to locale. But it does pull in other company dependencies and unsure if any of them is causing any side effects. Wonder if there is a way to just force the format and ignore any settings.

Comment: The passed locale in your code is completely ignored: 

`console.log(result);  - ko-KR May 10, 2020, 12:50`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @DonaldDuck In this case it is fine. It is to show the SAME code (also in plain text in the question) gives DIFFERENT results

Comment: In the console I cannot force other locales, in JSFiddle I can: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dgupxco9/ - same code in the console on the US site gives `May 10  2020 @ 12:50` and `May 10  2020 @ 12:50`

Comment: @mplungjan Believe JSFiddle outcome is similar to trying this logic on an empty tab in browser console.

Comment: @keshk Correct. A new incognito window works

Answer (score -1):

The main reason is that you are using the `replace` method, which is only changing the first comma it finds. But the way dates are formatted can vary, so sometimes there might be one comma, sometimes two, or even none.

To get the format you want simply change the colon in the time to a period. So instead of "11:50" you get "11.50"

```
const formatDateTime = (userLocale, dateTimeFormat, date) => {
    return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString(userLocale, dateTimeFormat)
        .replace(':', '.');
};
```

Comment: _"But the way dates are formatted can vary"_ - but that _should_ not be the case to begin with here, when they are using `toLocaleDateString` in the first place to _create_ that date representation.

Comment: Did you meant to paste something else? This is the exact code I have.

Comment: My bad! fixed :)
@CBroe The toLocaleDateString formats the date based on the provided locale and options. For 'en-GB' and the date '2020-05-09T22:50:21.817Z', it might produce "09 May 2020, 11:50 pm". Your first replace method replaces the first comma with a space, resulting in "09 May 2020 11:50 pm". Your second replace method is looking for another comma to replace with ' @', but there isn't another comma, so it does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, fine - but how does _any_ of that explain the actual situation discussed here, that this gives different results in two different tabs in the same browser ...?

Comment: So besically the toLocaleDateString relies on the browsers internal implementation and the systems locale settings. If there is difference in the environment or if there is browser extension or script that might be affecting the global Date object or its prototype it can lead to that. Another thinf is the browser might have different settings or cached data for different tabs or sessions. I'd make sure that both tabs are in the exact same environment with no external scripts or extensions interfering